# GEOSException: bad allocation when using pygeos geopandas buffer

Tags: geopandas, memory, geos, memoryerror

I am running python 3.10 through Spyder with geopandas 0.12.0, geos 3.11.0 and pygeos 0.13.

I am trying to buffer a shapefile containing lines. I have used this script on a similar dataset before and it worked without problems. But now, for some reason it keeps giving out memory errors, even when working with only a small subset of the data. I have tried to run the script on only 10 of the 2000 shapes, both in memory and from a separate file of only 8mb, but it still gives a memory error. My code is:

```
gdf='shapefile_containing_lines'
gdf = gpd.read_file(gdf)
gdf['geometry'] = gdf.buffer(2, resolution=4)
gdf.to_file('output_shapefile')
```

This is the full error message I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "...\Anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "...\my_script.py", line 12, in <module>
    gdf['geometry'] = gdf.buffer(2, resolution=4)

  File "...\Anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py", line 2874, in buffer
    return _delegate_geo_method(

  File "...\Anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py", line 81, in _delegate_geo_method
    data = getattr(a_this, op)(*args, **kwargs).data

  File "...\Anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\geopandas\array.py", line 614, in buffer
    vectorized.buffer(self.data, distance, resolution=resolution, **kwargs),

  File "...\Anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_vectorized.py", line 869, in buffer
    return pygeos.buffer(data, distance, quadsegs=resolution, **kwargs)

  File "...\Anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\pygeos\decorators.py", line 80, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "...\Anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\pygeos\constructive.py", line 175, in buffer
    return lib.buffer(

GEOSException: bad allocation
```